# Media queries in Chrome off by about 20 pixels

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I'm creating a responsive site. My media queries work fine in Safari, but I get an extra 20px or so in Chrome and Firefox, which causes a horizontal scroll bar to pop up before going into "mobile mode," which causes my columns to expand to 100%.

My media queries say to expand columns to 100% when 540px is reached, but Chrome seems to like to wait until 520px for some reason. I'm wondering if some margin I've forgotten about is still there. I can upload my site for you guys: http://dustindowell.com/site.

My media queries are here, but I don't think that has anything to do with the extra space.

```
@media (orientation:portrait){
    div.pageContainer,
    div.bannerTitle{ width:auto;}

    div.mainColumn{
        width:-webkit-calc(100% - 1.5em);
        width:        calc(100% - 1.5em);
        box-shadow:0 .125em 0 0 hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);}

    div.postPreviewContainer{
        width:-webkit-calc(100% - 1.5em);
        width:        calc(100% - 1.5em);}

    div.toggler{
        margin-top:1.5em; /* makes room for banner title */
        margin-bottom:1.5em;} /* pushes down banner title */

    div.sideColumn{
        width:-webkit-calc(100% - 1.25em);
        width:        calc(100% - 1.25em);}
}

@media (orientation:portrait)
and (min-width:540px) and (max-width:1080px){
    div.postPreviewContainer{
        width:-webkit-calc((100% / 2) - 1.5em);
        width:        calc((100% / 2) - 1.5em);}
}
```

Comment: You do realize that most mobile devices don't support `calc()`, right?  http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, chrome and firefox don't include the scrollbar as part of the width, while safari does. I don't like that behavior, I'll have to see what I can do to fix it.